# __DIR__ and DOCUMENT_ROOT return different values, but both work. Why?

Tags: php

I have saved this code as dr.php in the root of a client's host. As could be seen in the output, `__DIR__` is different from `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`; but they both find the `dr.php`.

What is going on? Is it safe to assume `DOCUMENT_ROOT` *always* works?

*Code of dr.php*

```
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
var_dump(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dr.php'));
var_dump(__DIR__);
var_dump(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/dr.php'));
?>
</pre>
```

*The output*

```
string(36) "/usr/local/etc/httpd/htdocs/daikaidk"
bool(true)
string(34) "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/daikaidk"
bool(true)
```

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is server environment, which is set according to server preferences, so in some wicked cases it could probably fail. While magic constant will always work, and it shows **directory**.

Comment: they are different things, read the documentation.

Comment: @Grimv01k, my expectation was that this *was* one of those wicked cases. I wonder why it works though.

Comment: `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/daikaidk` is real folder for site root. `/usr/local/etc/httpd/htdocs/daikaidk` is symlink to this folder. You can use function realpatch for check it.

Comment: it *usually* works. that doesn't mean you should rely on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

> __DIR__ : The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname(__FILE__). This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory.

and

> __FILE__    The full path and filename of the file **with symlinks resolved**. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is 
>   returned.

So, you have configured your web server (Apache) with `DOCUMENT ROOT` `/usr/local/etc/httpd/htdocs/daikaidk` that's a symbolic link to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/daikaidk`.

In PHP `__DIR__` returns the real path with symlinks resolved.